# Data.table: square brackets used with j

Tags: r, data.table

So I am trying to learn `data.table`and came accros the `.SD`notation in a cheat sheet online [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf). So the example uses square brackets with `.SD` to subset rows. But why not just subset rows with `i`? So `.SD[c(1, .N)]`subsets rows right? And why should I subset rows like this?

```
    library(data.table)

    DT <- data.table(A = letters[c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)], 
                     B = 1:5, 
                     C = 6:10)

    DT
    #>    A B  C
    #> 1: a 1  6
    #> 2: a 2  7
    #> 3: a 3  8
    #> 4: b 4  9
    #> 5: b 5 10

 # Method 1   
    DT[, .SD[c(1, .N)], by = A]
    #>    A B  C
    #> 1: a 1  6
    #> 2: a 3  8
    #> 3: b 4  9
    #> 4: b 5 10

# method 2
    DT[c(1, .N), .SD, by = A]
    #>    A B  C
    #> 1: a 1  6
    #> 2: b 5 10
```

Comment: you can check useful info about `.SD` in new vignette: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/doc/datatable-sd-usage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, we are specifying the `i` with index where `.N` is the last row, while in first case, it is the last row of each group

```
DT[c(1, .N)]
```

is similar to

```
DT[c(1, .N), .SD, by = A]
```

Only difference is that the rows specified in the `i` would be used for processing/changing for grouping info `by` 'A'

Comment: Okay so the difference is when I use `by` that it subsets based on the groups while `i` subsetting never considers `by`.

Comment: @David I would say what ever rows you specified in the `i` would be available for  further processing

Comment: @David If you are new to data.table I suggest you take a look at this cheat sheet : https://ugoproto.github.io/ugo_r_doc/datatable.pdf . It can really help while you are learning data.table.